# Translate in aiohttp

Tags: internationalization, aiohttp

There is some app with aiohttp used just for REST.
Front written in React/Redux.

The most part of application is translated on Frontend side.
But there are also message generated by aiohttp on server side (for example messages about form validation).
What's the best practise to handle these messages?
Make all translation on Frontend side?

Answer (score 0):

There is https://github.com/jie/aiohttp_babel
Did not use it yet though